# Convert HTML DIV to a resusable global function?? Maybe Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a popup that i am using on my site and I am trying to figure out a way to shorten up the code. I have spent many years in the Visual Studio world with .NET and am used to using functions or modules to shorten my code, but in HTML, I am not 100% how to do this, or if it is even best practice to do so. Maybe even convert the entire thing into a CSS value?

I would want to change the classs based off the 1st variable, the title with 2nd variable and the text with the 3rd.

Here is the code that I am using:

```css
.popupalert {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font: 1.5em'Andale Mono', Consolas, 'Courier New';
}
.popupsuccess {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font: 1.5em'Andale Mono', Consolas, 'Courier New';
}
.popupwarning {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #f47836;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font: 1.5em'Andale Mono', Consolas, 'Courier New';
}
.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='popupwarning'>
  <span class='closebtn' onclick=\ "this.parentElement.style.display='none';\">&times;</span>
  <strong>NOTICE!</strong> The quota increase is larger than the volume free space.
</div>
```

What I would like to have is a function or javascript that I can run on any page (with script loaded of course). I have 3 different levels of popups (alert, warning, success). I would like to pass the alert level, and the text string. like this:

```html
    <script>
        popup('warning','NOTICE!','some text to go with alert')
    </script>
```

Comment: You mean in pure javascript or maybe using jQuery?

Comment: If your goal is to set conditions to change your view dinamically then you should use AngularJs. That's one of it's main purpose.

Comment: I agree with @xoxel, you should really be using some kind of UI framework to do this kind of thing.  Something like Angular (although it does much more than that) or ReactJS which is probably apt for this situation.

Comment: here is a solution with pure javascript http://plnkr.co/edit/GFtGNRO3gyg9euVoCh0h

Comment: I think Vladu Ionut is the option I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to shorten up your CSS code and make a function that returns the popup `HTML` code. First, I would start by reducing your CSS code. If you look at your CSS, `popupalert`, `popupsuccess`, and `popupwarning` all have pretty much the same CSS with the exception of the `background color`. Why not create a popup class that has the base CSS for the popup, then create the different color classes for the background? That would reduce it a bit. Something like this:

```
.popup {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font: 1.5em'Andale Mono', Consolas, 'Courier New';
}
```

Then you could create a child class that sets the background like so:

```
.popup .alert{
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.popup .success{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.popup .warning{
  background-color: #f47836;
}
```

Now, usually I wouldn't worry about creating a function to spit out HTML code, but if you need something like that, you could do something like this:

```
function popupGenerator(type, title, body) {

     // return the html string here. You will have to construct it yourself.

}
```

Now that you have the function that spits out the proper html, you could just use it like this when the page loads, someone hits a button, etc:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("body").append(popupGenerator("warning", "my warning", "do something"));

});
```

I've made a little **JSBIN** to help you out. You'll have to do some tweaking to your fitting, but this should give you a start: 
http://jsbin.com/xuquwacoju/edit?js,output

Comment: I like the CSS portion of your answer but not the returning of an HTML string.  Wouldn't it be better to utilize something like jQuery to pass in the DOM element and manipulate that instead?  Technically both are pretty horrible but it seems like that would be better.

Comment: @Willwsharp The CSS part is about as clean as you're going to get it. If you use some sort CSS framework, you could probably get it a little better, but for normal CSS, I think that's as good as it will get. As far as the html function, I thought you needed a function that returned HTML, that's why I wrote that. I don't know what your app looks like so it's kind of tough to write the best way to tackle this. However, if the popup is already generated on the screen and you just need to edit the title, body, etc, then yes, I would just use JQuery and pass in the ID/Class to target

Comment: Oh I'm not the OP, was just adding on for maybe a better answer.

Comment: @Willwsharp ahh, gotcha. I just assumed you were the OP, ha! There are so many different ways to tackle things with JS/jQuery (as you know). It's tough to say what the best thing to do in the OP's situation is. If his element is already rendered on the page, I would totally just pass in the DOM element and let the function alter it. However, when I wrote the answer, I was assuming that the element wasn't rendered and that he wanted a function to generate and render it onto the page.

Comment: I do like the CSS portion. I will definitely do that to shorten it up the CSS.

Comment: @James yes I would agree with that logic.  Ideally, it would be best to have something like Angular here so we don't have to do any of this by hand!

Comment: @Willwsharp I prefer Aurelia. It's much better in my opinion! haha But yes, a framework like Aurelia or Angular would make this much easier!